# Laravel Lumen blank page on fresh installation

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-14.04, lumen

I have recently installed Lumen but it’s only showing a blank page without any error. I have already tried following:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 0777 storage
```

Tried to delete **compiled.php** but still no luck. Can you please help me to debug the issue? Thanks

Comment: Did you bother to check your web server error logs ?

Comment: @LuckyBurger not really, i can try that.

Comment: @seoppc You probably should have before posting here. That’s what error logs are for.

Comment: This only shows lack of effort.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen same issue several times. I have always been able to resolve it by looking at the error_log file.

Most often it is related to storage file permissions which you have set properly. Another common option is to have some of the Laravel PHP dependencies missing like mcrypt.